# Examples of non-cubulated hyperbolic groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

What is known regarding which hyperbolic groups are cubulated?

I take it the usual definition of cubulated is acting properly and cocompactly on a CAT(0)-cube complex.

My impression is that not all of them are, but I didn't manage to find references with a counterexample.

Are there known ways to create non-cubulated hyperbolic groups? 
Are there famous examples of non-cubulated groups?

Comment: A weaker notion, "PW" is just acting properly on a CAT(0) cube complex (possibly infinite-dimensional). It's much weaker than cubulable, still not satisfied by all hyperbolic groups (see AGenevois's answer), while satisfied by many groups.

Comment: The Ollivier-Wise Rips machine produces hyperbolic groups with an infinite Property T subgroup and arbitrary f.p. quotient (hence possibly without Property T). These hyperbolic groups don't have Property PW, hence are not cubulable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If a group $G$ satisfies Kazhdan's property (T), then any action of $G$ on a CAT(0) cube complex has a global fixed point. See Niblo and Roller's article *Groups acting on cubes and Kazhdan's Property (T)*. Examples of hyperbolic groups which satisfy this property include:

- Uniform lattices in quaternionic hyperbolic spaces.
- Random groups in Gromov's model for some density.

Also, by a theorem due to Gromov, any hyperbolic group admits a quotient which is hyperbolic and has property (T).

Comment: Do you know if uniform lattices in quaternionic hyperbolic spaces have torsion or are torsion free?

Comment: I am not quite familiar with lattices in quaternionic hyperbolic spaces, but there are reflections in such spaces, so I would say that there exist torsion-free lattices and lattices with torsion.

Comment: @YanivShakhar: They're linear, and hence virtually torsion free. Probably there are explicit examples of quaterionionic hyperbolic lattices with torsion, but if you want to construct a hyperbolic group with torsion and property (T), just take any non-trivial element $g$ and kill a sufficiently high power $g^n$.

Answer (score 6):

As @AGenevois says in his answer, the standard examples of non-cubulated hyperbolic groups are those with Kazhdan's property (T), such as quaternionic hyperbolic lattices.

Complex hyperbolic lattices (in dimension >2) provide a more delicate class of examples.  On the one hand, they are not cubulable, by a theorem of [Delzant--Py](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.08474).  On the other hand, they are known to have the [Haagerup property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haagerup_property) (I think this is proved in the book by Bekka--de la Harpe--Valette), so they also don't have property (T).

As far as I know, they are the only class of examples of hyperbolic groups known to be Haagerup but non-cubulable. I'd be interested to hear of others.

Comment: That they're Haagerup is a 1974 result of Faraut-Harzallah.

Comment: You can get more examples by taking free products of uniform complex-hyperbolic lattices in $PU(n,1)$, $n\ge 2$. What is unknown, I think, is the existence of 2-dimensional hyperbolic groups which have the Haagerup property but do not admit cubulations.

Comment: @Misha — sure, but I wouldn’t class those as genuinely “different” examples.  I agree that 2-dimensional examples would be particularly nice to have.